# facebook app: cross domain error although it seems well set-up

Tags: facebook, web-applications, single-sign-on

I have a web app that runs on localhost or example.com. And I am loading the facebook apps sdk to be able to do Single Sign-On, but I have this error in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/impression.php. No 'Access-Control-
Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin
'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

whereas I have gone in the settings of the facebook app and enter `http://localhost/` or `http://example.com/` in the `Site URL` field.

Here's the screen capture of my local url for instance :

[image]

...and the corresponding setting my facebook app account :

[image]

I really need some help here please !

Comment: What is your web app url?

Comment: it is in private access for now, not released yet !

Comment: @jeekonline  it is in private access for now, not released yet. I can provide you with an access, in private, if you have time to help ?

Comment: All right :-) i don't want know url, but I thought of explain with url instead of example url !

Comment: @jeekonline I am not sure I understand, sorry !

Comment: Actually I am not sure I understand what is my Web app Url ....the url where the HTML/CSS/JS are located ?

Comment: Yes exactly, the web site url.

Comment: @jeekonline ok this is exaclty what I've put in the Site URL field (I tested http://localhost and my website url, let's say http:///example.com)...I still get the same error, both from my local machine and from my website....any idea what's going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Url given in SITE URL field must be match with your WEB URL [where facebook sdk invoked.]

Hence in your case, SITE URL field given : www.example.com 
Web App URL must be : www.example.com

Comment: it is the case : but does the "http://" counts, because on my website I have a redirection of all url to their counterpart without "http://"

Answer (score 0):

I'm running it locally under IIS Express using

`http://localhost:XXXXX/`

where XXXXX is the port number the website is running on and that works for me.

Comment: Thanks How do I get my port number on my local sever (Linux, Apache2) ?